# Duplicate specific cell values from one sheet to specific cells in another using Google script

Tags: google-apps-script

After spending 10 hours of figuring out a script, I'm going to give it a try and ask it here. I already read all of the relevant questions on Stackoverflow, but I still can't get my script work. I want two buttons on sheet1 (invoice). Button 1 duplicates cell values to sheet2 and Button 2 clears the content of the sheet. Button 2 is already working.

What the script for button 1 needs to do:

Duplicate cell values from sheet1 to sheet2. But the difficult part (for me) is that the cells are specific (B4, C12, C13, F29, F30) and they need to be duplicated to the first free row on sheet2, but in specific columns  (F6, B6, D6, G6, I6). And I don't know how to do this.

After trying a lot of scripts I'm now having this:

```
    function DuplicatetoSheet2()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('B4:F30');  
  var data = range.getValues();

  var ts = "sheet2";
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, ??? ).setValues(data);
}
```

And since sheet1 is an invoice I also tried this piece of code, but I don't know if I can use it:

```
var client = sheet.getRange("B4").getValue();
var dateInvoice = sheet.getRange("C12").getValue();
var numInvoice = sheet.getRange("C13").getValue();
var subtotal = sheet.getRange("F29").getValue();
var vat = sheet.getRange("F30").getValue();
```

I really hope that someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `specific columns (F6, B6, D6, G6, I6)` do you mean column F, B, D, G, I ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
function moveFromInvoiceSheetToSheet2() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SHEET_1_NAME");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SHEET_2_NAME");
  var last_row = sheet2.getLastRow(); //This will fetch the last row index = first free row
  // copyTo can also be used instead of moveTo
  sheet1.getRange("B4").moveTo(sheet2.getRange(last_row + 1, 6)); //F = 6
  sheet1.getRange("C12").moveTo(sheet2.getRange(last_row + 1, 2)); //B = 2
  sheet1.getRange("C13").moveTo(sheet2.getRange(last_row + 1, 4)); //D = 4
  sheet1.getRange("F29").moveTo(sheet2.getRange(last_row + 1, 7)); //G = 7
  sheet1.getRange("F30").moveTo(sheet2.getRange(last_row + 1, 9)); //I = 9
}
```

You don't need to clear content after copying because you're moving. If you want you can use `copyTo` also

Comment: Thanks for your help! It copies al the data to the first free row on sheet2. But when I clear the content of the invoice, what I need to do to make a new invoice, the data on sheet2 is also erased. I know I need to put getValues somewhere, but I don't know where exactly.

Another thing, the script puts the data in row 255, I guess it's because the cells of the first 254 rows are all having borders around them? Is that something you can adjust in the script?

Comment: You can use your clear button for new invoice. You'll need to debug that border issue, try removing border and then running script, see where data goes and so on

https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers